# NSOpenPanel freezes app for few seconds

Tags: cocoa

I'm using NSOpenPanel this way:

```
    NSOpenPanel *op=[NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    [op setDelegate:self];
    [op setCanChooseFiles:YES];
    [op setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
    [op setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
    [op setPrompt:NSLocalizedString(@"Scan this",@"button of 'scan folder' open panel")];
    [op setAccessoryView:nil];
    [op setMessage:@""];

    if ( [op runModalForDirectory:nil file:nil] == NSOKButton )
    {
        [self scanPaths:[op filenames] automatic:NO];
        [[ScanController sharedController] setCurrentScanSidebarDriveName: @"(Custom)"];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"cancel clicked");
    }
```

When I click "Cancel", the app runs to end of my method and then freeze for a while (few seconds). I think that this part of my code is ok. Or not? When it falls, my debugger gets crazy (At&T..). :/ Is there any way how to debug this kind of problem? Have anyone seen that?
Thank you.

Comment: This is happening to me as well when showing the NSOpenPanel as a sheet. I think it might be related to QuickLook not being able to generate a preview for the selected item and locking upon close of the panel.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the open panel freeze the app for a few seconds when external media that's been suspended/put on standby takes awhile to spin back up but never when hitting Cancel. Have you used Instruments (Time Profiler) to find out what it's doing at that point?

Comment: The one I mentioned in my answer: Time Profiler.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it..but without any useful outputs.. There is no external media connected. When I click "Scan this", everything works ok.

Comment: Not helpful? I doubt that. Are you sure you're interpreting what you're seeing correctly? You should narrow the scope to be between the point you click "cancel" (by watching where the time pointer is in the graph) and the point operation resumes. Then look at where it's spending most of its time in the table (make sure you include system libraries instead of just your own code).